Alerts from Tradingview.com do not select sides (BUY/SELL) and get copied multiple 5 times each with capitalise.ai
I created a tradingview.com strategy that is ready to automate. And I have found that capitalize.ai (cap.ai from here) is able to execute my trades from tradingview (TV from hereon), via an API to Avatrade and Interactive Brokers.
The problem however is limited to webhook alerts from TV to cap.ai.
I enclose my alert and tradelogic code below. Does any one know of why I get 10 (5 SELL and 5 BUY alerts, every time the alert triggers. And cap.ai does not trigger on my alerts/webhooks, which have proper msg and URL).
My code for alerts and tradelogic
// Alert Messages long
ANDstartLongTradeMessage = input.string(title = "Long Entry Webhook Message", defval = "", group = "Long Webhook Messages")
ANDendLongTradeMessage = input.string(title = "Close Long Webhook Message", defval = "", group = "Long Webhook Messages")

// Alert Messages short
ANDstartShortTradeMessage = input.string(title = "Short Entry Webhook Message", defval = "", group = "Short Webhook Messages")
ANDendShortTradeMessage = input.string(title = "Close Short Webhook Message", defval = "", group = "Short Webhook Messages")

// ------------------- Trading signals and Alerts  -----------------  See section on alerts above ANDTradelogic
// All orders have the same but dynamic text, that will show the direction of order
alertsyntax = '{{strategy.order.action}}  - - - Machine Learning: Logistic Regression (ME v.6 - DynTP & SL) (Close, , 3, 2, 0.0009, 1000, None, 5, 7, 1, 2023, 1, 1, 2029, 6, 0.01): 
     order {{strategy.order.action}} @ {{strategy.order.contracts}} filled on {{ticker}}. New strategy position is {{strategy.position_size}}' 
// Alerts in TV GUI will work with this message: {{ticker}} - {{strategy.order.action}} {{strategy.order.contracts}} @ {{strategy.order.price}}. New strategy position is {{strategy.position_size}} {{strategy.order.alert_message}}


// -------------------------------------------------------------------------

// ----------------   ANDTradelogic Fct   ------------------------------  Bruges nu til handler for at minimere antal trades 

ANDTradelogic(close) =>
    if ANDstartLongTrade
        strategy.entry('Long', strategy.long) //
        if use_TP 
            strategy.exit("Exit Long, TP", from_entry="Long", limit=high * (1+(tpPercent/100)))
        alert(message=alertsyntax, freq=alert.freq_all)   //, freq=alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)   
        alert(ANDendShortTradeMessage, freq = alert.freq_once_per_bar)
        alert(ANDstartLongTradeMessage, freq = alert.freq_once_per_bar)

    if ANDstartShortTrade
        strategy.entry('Short', strategy.short)
        if use_TP 
            strategy.exit("Exit Short, TP", from_entry="Short", limit=low * (1-(tpPercent/100)))
        alert(message=alertsyntax, freq=alert.freq_all) //, freq=alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)   
        alert(ANDendLongTradeMessage, freq = alert.freq_once_per_bar)
        alert(ANDstartShortTradeMessage, freq = alert.freq_once_per_bar)

    // Final decision of when to trade
    if ANDendShortTrade
        strategy.close('Long', 'Long')
        alert(message=alertsyntax) //, freq=alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)   
        alert(ANDendShortTradeMessage, freq = alert.freq_once_per_bar)

    if ANDendLongTrade
        strategy.close('Short', 'Short')
        alert(message=alertsyntax) //, freq=alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)   
        alert(ANDendLongTradeMessage, freq = alert.freq_once_per_bar)


if window()  // if in timewindow of trading/backtest

    // Run ANDTradelogic Fct.
    ANDTradelogic (close)


I am expecting that cap.ai can use my alerts to dynamically from my TV strategy code, get the direction of the trade (BUY/SELL) and the quantity, which change over time. So a hardcoded cap.ai will not do. This is too constrained.
When I do backtest of this strategy on TV, the backtest properly trades both ways, and the quantity evolves like so: BUY x, Short 2x, buy 2x, short 2x.... etc.

You get 10 alerts and I can count 10 alert() functions so it seems they all get triggered resp all if statemens in the ANDTradelogic function seem to be true. If you haven´t done this already, I suggest  temporarily replacing the alerts with labels to see where and why they are triggered. Or try an if / else logic, you don´t go long and short and the same time, do you?

Check out the documentation and examples posted on the Capitalise web
Use only box input strings
something like this:
// Alert Messages long
ANDstartLongTradeMessage  = input.string(title = "Long Entry Webhook Message", defval = "", group = "Long Webhook Messages")
ANDendLongTradeMessage    = input.string(title = "Close Long Webhook Message", defval = "", group = "Long Webhook Messages")

// Alert Messages short
ANDstartShortTradeMessage = input.string(title = "Short Entry Webhook Message", defval = "", group = "Short Webhook Messages")
ANDendShortTradeMessage   = input.string(title = "Close Short Webhook Message", defval = "", group = "Short Webhook Messages")

if ANDstartLongTrade
    strategy.entry('Long', strategy.long) //
    alert(ANDstartLongTradeMessage, freq = alert.freq_once_per_bar)

if ANDendLongTrade
    strategy.close('Long', 'Long')
    alert(ANDendLongTradeMessage, freq = alert.freq_once_per_bar)

if ANDstartShortTrade
    strategy.entry('Short', strategy.short)
    alert(ANDstartShortTradeMessage, freq = alert.freq_once_per_bar)

if ANDendShortTrade
    strategy.close('Short', 'Short')
    alert(ANDendShortTradeMessage, freq = alert.freq_once_per_bar)


Can you please elaborate on what you mean by 'box input strings'.
I have gotten my alerts to trigger with the alerts like this            alert('{"alertId": "xxxxxxxxxxxx"}'). There is then only 1 alert that takes its position direction from the tradelogic. This seems to work. But how do my strategy convey to cap.ai that I want to enter with 95% of my capital in each trade? Apparantly cap.ai only accept to purchase x number of stock.. is should get the value from my tradingview strategy.

Copy: https://i.imgur.com/diHyqYt.png and Paste: https://i.imgur.com/1v8UoBC.png

When you create a trigger in cap.ai, you define the size of the position

This is a fixed way of strategy.entry. I have defined everything pertaining to order quantity in the Tradingview strategy, and would like cap.ai to use this info in the alerts and the orders.
Is that possible? I know where to put URL and Alert id from Cap.ai thanks.
